# How will you manage this step inside a wizard? Hard level: external plugins and valid signatures certificates needed

Tags: wizard, document, signs

I'll try to explain myself as best as I can:

I need to create a flow for sign documents in bulk. I mean, the user selects in a table a number of documents, and then the user applies the sign to all these documents.

How am I managing that? With a fullscreen wizard:

**1 step:** choose the sign type (without certification -easy, add only your name; and with certification -the complex way, using plugins and this stuff)

**2 step** review the selection of the documents (the list with the documents ready to be signed, nothing complex)

**3 step** result of the action (signed or error)

So, my problem is in the first step, with when you select the "sign with certificate" option because:

-First, we check (automatically) if there is a browser extension installed. If not, we should redirect to the extension install.

-Second, if we found the previous extension, we show a list of valid sign certificates previously installed by the user. So the user selects one and continues with the wizard. OR, if the user doesn't have the signature certificate, we show the URLs to install one of the supported certificates

You can see here where all this should happen (low fidelity, sorry, haha):
[image: Step 1 in the wizard]

I'm not sure how to add these things inside a selection inside a step. I thought **of adding a spinner** ie: "checking certificates". The result of this operation will be:

-No extension found: "You need to install X extension"
-Extension found, but no certificates found: "You need to add any of these valid sign certificates"
-Extension and certificates found: "Select a valid certificate"

**In summary: spinner + required action.**

[image: spinner]

[image: spinner2]

What do you think about this approach? I feel that this is a complex situation :/

PS: Sorry for my English

Comment: Try creating a taskflow to think through the rules.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is almost there, to improve user experience you may like to show the stage which the application is checking. I'm saying specifically for this screen.

[image: screen taken off the question]

What you write in the "bla bla bla" is important, e.g. you can consider to put one of the following stages as the extension check runs in the background

- Checking for extension
- Searching for certificates
- Verifying the validity of certificates

Then the results should show either of the following actions

- No extension found...
- No certificates found...
- No valid certificates found...
- Valid certificates found, please select one from list

(Do note the results are incomplete, a complete error message should give constructive feedback to what users should do to rectify the error.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback. We finally change the approach because of technical problems with the certificates provider, but thanks a lot for the good feedback :D